# Matlab Cropping Plots

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I want to adjust the amount of whitespace that is shown when plots are generated. I found this command to do just that:

```
set(gca,'LooseInset',get(gca,'TightInset'))
```

But this doesn't work that well when I add axis labels. When I have a plot without axis labels it's fine, it looks like this:
[image]

But when I add labels it does this:
[image]

You can't see it all that well but there is a lot of white space left of the yaxis label. I want to crop it down to the bare minimum, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set( gca, 'Position', get( gca, 'OuterPosition' ) - ...
  get( gca, 'TightInset' ) * [-1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1] );
```

Here is an example of what the above does:

```
figure
plot( 1:10 )
ylabel( 'Y Axis' );
xlabel( 'X Axis' );
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

And side-by-side before the printing:

[image]

Comment: no that didn't work...i'm still getting some big whitespace on the left.

Comment: @Richard It does for me. I added an example before and after to my answer. I am using R2013a, but I know other people that have used the same method on many other versions.

Comment: are the ellipses supposed to be there? I hope that's not a stupid question, I'm new to matlab so I'm not a 100% on the syntax yet. Also I changed the font size of the x and y axis labels along with the title, is that going to change anything?

Comment: @Richard Sorry. I copy-pasted from a function. The ellipses mean that the line of code continues after the new line. If everything is typed on the same line, then you can remove them.

Comment: yah I have no idea why it's not working. I've just went ahead and used [this file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35464-spaceplots) to control whitespaces. But I'll mark this right since it works for you. Thanks!